# Seed Method Doesn't Populate Tables

Tags: entity-framework-6, seeding

The database is create successfully as well as the tables. However, whether I put the seed code in the configuration file or as a initializer. The tables are never populated with data.

Things I have tried:
1. I have been viewed several posts on stackoverflow comparing my code with solutions to no avail.
2. I changed DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges to DropCreateDatabaseAlways, still the same.
3. I have verified all required fields have a value

```
public class BankAccountInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<BankAccountContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(BankAccountContext context)
    {

        var bank1 = new Bank(1) { BankName = "Huntington", BankAccounts = new List<BankAccount>() };

        context.Banks.Add(bank1);

        context.BankAccounts.Add
        (
            new CheckingAccount(1)
            {
                BankId = 1,
                AccountBalance = 25.00m,
                BankAccountName = "Checking Account 1",
                DateAdded = DateTime.Now,
                RoutingNumber = 00000887,
                Owner = "Checking Account Owner 1",
                Bank = bank1
            }
        );

        context.BankAccounts.Add
        (
              new IndividualInvestment(2)
              {
                  BankId = 1,
                  AccountBalance = 10.00m,
                  BankAccountName = "Individual Investment 1",
                  DateAdded = DateTime.Now,
                  RoutingNumber = 00000887,
                  Owner = "Individual Investment Owner 1",
                  Bank = bank1
              }
        );

        context.BankAccounts.Add(

            new CorporateInvestment(3)
            {
                BankId = 1,
                AccountBalance = 98.00m,
                BankAccountName = "Corporate Investment 1",
                DateAdded = DateTime.Now,
                RoutingNumber = 00000887,
                Owner = "Corporate Investment Owner 1",
                Bank = bank1
            }
         );

        base.Seed(context);
   }
}
```

}

Comment: I was finally able to figure out the issue. I quit using the Initializer and put the code in the Configuration.cs file and it worked.

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out! When you can, please answer or close this question.